# How to parse Anchor event in Rust?

Tags: anchor, rust

My Anchor program emits the following event

```
"events": [
    {
      "name": "SwapEvent",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "market",
          "type": "publicKey",
          "index": false
        },
        {
          "name": "amountIn",
          "type": "u64",
          "index": false
        },
        {
          "name": "amountOut",
          "type": "u64",
          "index": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

After reading [this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/how-to-parse-event-in-transaction-log-with-anchor), I'm able to decode the event in Typescript using Anchor and the IDL like this-

```
    const logs = [
      "Program 3Zg1z6Yfuv4vAkVcm1j3jxhb1QqF3DPzn7uaf3jeNqwo invoke [1]",
      "Program log: Instruction: Swap",
      "Program data: QMbN6CYIceImFhONSTJ9v+fhBJjmI31WGVv/Sh2Sk7A+XIdf2DosgugDAAAAAAAA5wMAAAAAAAA=",
      "Program 3Zg1z6Yfuv4vAkVcm1j3jxhb1QqF3DPzn7uaf3jeNqwo consumed 1244 of 200000 compute units",
      "Program 3Zg1z6Yfuv4vAkVcm1j3jxhb1QqF3DPzn7uaf3jeNqwo success"
    ]

    const decodedEvent = program.coder.events.decode('QMbN6CYIceImFhONSTJ9v+fhBJjmI31WGVv/Sh2Sk7A+XIdf2DosgugDAAAAAAAA5wMAAAAAAAA=')
    console.log(decodedEvent)
```

What is the equivalent way to parse the event in Rust?